# React Redux Template module Babel-Loader build fails

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm learning Redux with the redux.js.org essentials tutorial and everything was working fine until I added a feature and now I'm getting this error.

I read many post here and it seems to be related to the babel module but on my case I didn't install this module because it was part of the template used for the tutorial, plus it's not included on my package.json so I'm not sure if that's the problem or not.

Hopefully somebody can see what I'm doing wrong.
Thanks very much.

[image]

This is my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "redux-essentials-example",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@mswjs/data": "^0.8.4",
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.6.1",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.1",
    "@testing-library/react": "^12.1.2",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "classnames": "^2.2.6",
    "date-fns": "^2.12.0",
    "faker": "^4.1.0",
    "miragejs": "^0.1.35",
    "mock-socket": "^9.0.3",
    "msw": "^0.36.3",
    "react": "^17",
    "react-dom": "^17",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.4",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.1.2",
    "react-scripts": "^4",
    "seedrandom": "^3.0.5",
    "txtgen": "^2.2.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts --openssl-legacy-provider start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "prettier": "^2.0.2"
  },
  "msw": {
    "workerDirectory": "public"
  }
}
```

This is my postSlice.js:

```
import {createSlice} from '@reduxjs/toolkit'
import {nanoid} from '@reduxjs/toolkit'
import {sub} from 'date-fns'

const initialState = [
{
    id: '1', title: 'Primer post', content: 'Hola como va', date: sub(new Date(), {minutes: 10}).toISOString()
},
{
    id: '2', title: 'Segundo post', content: 'Comentando ando',date: sub(new Date(), {minutes: 5}).toISOString()
}]

const postsSlice = createSlice({
    name : 'posts',
    initialState,
    reducers: {
        postAdded(state, action){
            state.push(action.payload)
        },

        prepare(title, content, userId) {
            return {
                payload: {
                    id: nanoid(),
                    date: new Date().toISOString(),
                    title,
                    content,
                    user: userId
                }
        }

        }
        postUpdated(state, action) {
            const {id, title, content} = action.payload
            const existingPost = state.find(post => post.id === id)
            if (existingPost){
                existingPost.title = title
                existingPost.content = content
            }
        }
    }
})
export const {postAdded, postUpdated} = postsSlice.actions

export default postsSlice.reducer
```

Comment: What is on line 34 of PostSlice.js?

Comment: It is: postUpdated(state, action) {. Line 35 is const {id, title, content} = action.payload, 36: const existingPost = state.find(post => post.id === id). Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The error was that on my postSlice.js after the prepare() reducer I forgot to add a comma for the next reducer function postUpdated().